# DateDiff Not Working while trying to extract hour difference

Tags: vba

I've got this code and it returns nothing

```
Duration_Value = DateDiff("h", Start_Time_Value, EndTime)
```

Start_Time_Value = "23/08/2021 08:07:16.803"

EndTime = "24/08/2021 08:07:18.412"

Is there any reason why this might not be working?

Update:
The dates are extracted from cells in the workbook

```
'The end time value is the last value on column A
    lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    EndTime_Range = "A" & lrow
    EndTime = Range(EndTime_Range).Value

'The Start Time value is the first value on column A that is a date
For i = 1 To 15

Start_Time_Value = Worksheets(sheet_name).Range("A" & i).Value

On Error Resume Next
Start_Time_Value_new = Left(Start_Time_Value, 8)
If IsDate(Start_Time_Value_new) = True Then Exit For


Next i

MsgBox i
```

Comment: Are `Start_Time_Value` and `EndTime` both actual dates? Or are they strings that look like dates? Your examples sure look like they are actually strings, not dates. Convert them to actual dates first.

Comment: @braX how can I figure that out? also, is there a way I could convert it into date if I wanted to?

Comment: @braX that still gives me "Empty" as a result when I use DateDiff

Comment: @braX they are extracted from cells in the workbook.  I'll update my code in a second.

Comment: You will need to trim off the (eg) ".803" part of the strings before using CDate() on the reset.  `CDate(Split("23/08/2021 08:07:16.803",".")(0))`

Comment: @braX I have updated the code now

Comment: @TimWilliams that worked perfectly! if you submit this as an answer I can select it as the solution to my problem.